# Can the Font for a UWP Drag and Drop (DragUI) caption be changed?

Tags: xaml, uwp, fonts, drag-and-drop

I am implementing drag and drop for a UWP application and all is working well, except for the Font on the DragUI caption.

I have DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = True and DragUIOverride.Caption = "My Text String",

but does anyone know how to change the font?  My application uses a unique font and the system font stick out like a sore thumb.

(On a similar vein, I had the same issue with ToolTips, but figured out how to set a new style for ToolTip in <Application.Resources>, but I cant seem to find anything (i.e. a TargetType) for the DragUI text.)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the Font for a UWP Drag and Drop (DragUI) caption be changed?

I'm afraid, you can't change the font style for `DragUIOverride.Caption`, currently, there is not such api to change `Caption` font, it was manage by the system. And you could post your requirement with windows feed back hub.

And we have a workaround that use `SetContentFromBitmapImage` method insert text image  to replace `DragUIOverride.Caption`. For more please refer [XamlDragAndDrop](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop) code sample

Comment: Thanks Nico.  I actually was able to follow sample code and use in my application. But, while that was an interesting exercise, in the end it cannot solve my specific problem and I had to roll back.  I'll have to go with the 'ugly' text for now.

Comment: I have upvoted and marked as the correct answer because it is the only possible answer and I learned something new.  But unfortunately, just not a very good one for my use case (showing a drag image and formatted text at the same time).  I also did post to the Windows Feedback Hub as suggested.